# Make Yarn.lock resolved url Dynamic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-codeartifact

We're using AWS code artifact for npm package management.

When we install packages from aws code artifact, `yarn.lock` would be generated similar to below:

```yaml
"@rn/my-package@0.0.1":
  version "0.0.1"
  resolved "https://domain-account_id.d.codeartifact.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443/npm/npm/@dc/my-package/-/my-package-0.0.1.tgz#afgfewiget8927824tbjkda8y"
  integrity sha512-I1hlweIiynWDutmOaqzHdObrQebE7GvCTnbNeVcZn5hKYfldQPs2ct6SbTAhYbKnQoJjfJYBhoq5tXUnMalB7w==
```

Here is the URL in the **resolved** will be expired after 12 hrs (code artifact security feature to limit auth token to expire after 12 hrs)

How can we use current registry credentials for **resolved** key, from `.npmrc or some env variables?